# Why is my tableView not being populated?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to populate a basic tableview with sample data in code. Here's my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var postTableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postcell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "title"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "detail"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is my storyboard
[image]

I'm sure that the name `"postcell"` is correct and that I've hooked up the tableView to the ViewController as a datasource and delegate.

When I run the code in the iOS simulator, no cells show up. This is what I see:

[image]

Here are the constraints on my stack view
[image]

stack view properties

[image]
[image]

I don't want to use `UITableViewController`

How do I get the table cells to appear?

Comment: In your storyboard, have you made sure the class of the view controller is `TableViewController`?

Comment: @MrSaturn Yes, It's TableViewController

Comment: @MrSaturn I've added my storyboard, does that help?

Comment: Kind of. Now I'm thinking it has something to do with your stack view, but I'm not sure what. If you take your table view out of the stack view and constrain it to all four sides of your view controller's view, do any cells show up?

Comment: @MrSaturn, Yeah, now it does. How would the stack view affect that?

Comment: Oh okay. Hmm, not sure. It seems like your table view is getting sized down to zero width and height for some reason. What are the properties on your stack view? And the constraints on the stack view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147012/discussion-between-matthew-drill-and-mrsaturn).

Answer (score 2):

If "postcell" is not a prototype cell from your storyboard, you need to register it in your viewDidLoad:

```
    postTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postcell")
```

If it is a XIB table view cell you would register it as follows:

```
    postTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "postcell")
```

If you were to do it from storyboard, drag a prototype cell (or table view cell) onto your table view and in the reuse identifier call it "postcell" as shown here:

[image: Prototype table view cell]

Make sure you have also done the following in your viewDidLoad:

```
    postTableView.delegate = self
    postTableView.dataSource = self
```

Of course, you'll also need:

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

Comment: `numberOfSections(in:)` is not required. If you do not implement it, then one section is assumed.

Comment: Is there a way to make the cell a prototype cell in storyboard?

Comment: Yes. Simply drag a table view cell from your object library onto the table view and in the reuse identifier call it "postcell"

Comment: @gwinyai That's what I did. I didn't know that was called prototype cell. These suggestions aren't working for me. Also, I don't know if it's important, but the second `tableView` method isn't being called. (I tested it will print statements)

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are not getting something printed out in your second method if your dataSource and delegate is setup. But I've noticed your table view is embedded in a stack view in your view hierarchy. Could you take it out of the stack view and create new auto layout constraints just to test.

Comment: @gwinyai Yeah, MrSaturn pointed that out. I can see it without the stack view. How does the stack view affect this?

Comment: I assume that's because stackview tries to compress content as much as possible. When you initally add a tableview, I'm assuming it has no content, so stackview compresses the width to 0 because it has nothing to show. 
After the table gets populated with data, you have to set the tableView's frame, which is a bit of extra work you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postcell", for: indexPath) **as postcell** // add this line

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @MrSaturn for pointing out in the comments that it's a problem with the stack view. In storyboard I had to change the stack view's alignment property from center to Fill.